# What instructions can be used to perform a series of calculations in a calculator?

Tags: c#, blazor

I wrote a calculator program in the Blazor framework, but my code only runs the Calculate method once, and if I want to do another operation I have to run the program again, how can I solve this problem?

```
 public async Task Calculate()
    {

        if (Result != " ")
        {
            _firstnumber = double.Parse(Result);

            Result = " ";

            switch (_operand)
            {
                case "+":
                    Result = (_secondnumber + _firstnumber).ToString();
                    break;

                case "-":
                    Result = (_secondnumber - _firstnumber).ToString();
                    break;

                case "*":
                    Result = (_secondnumber * _firstnumber).ToString();
                    break;

                case "/":
                    Result = (_secondnumber / _firstnumber).ToString();
                    break;
            }
        }

        await LocalStorageService.SetItemAsync("Result", Result);
    }
```

You can see the full code in this link:
https://github.com/elnaz25/GitRepos

Comment: You will need to provide the code that shows how you see calling your calculate method so we can understand why it only calculates once

Comment: You can see the full code in this link: https://github.com/elnaz25/GitRepos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://lupblazorcalculator.z20.web.core.windows.net/
https://github.com/Lupusa87/BlazorCalculator
Please check my blazor calculator, I hope you will find answer.